# What's more cost effective in Parse... UIImages?

Tags: parse-platform

Is it more cost effective to upload a profile image to every social media post every time a post is added and just call one query to retrieve both the post and pic? Or is it more effective to have one database of user's pictures and run two queries, one looking up the posts and the other looking up the photos for the users?

First adds a countless number of photos but calls only one query each time.

Second does not but calls two queries.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should put the profile pic in the user table, not the post. The post should have a pointer to the user and when you want to display the pic, you'll get it from the user.

Yes, you will have to make two queries, not one, but the cost is low. Also, if the user updates her profile pic, you want to use that for all of her posts, not just new ones

With parse, you'll want to [include](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.9.0/Parse.Query.html#include) the user when you make the query for the post.